# Update the User Interface with dispatch_get_global_queue and Web Call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to learn to use `dispatch_get_global_queue` to perform a web call asynchronously. Basically, I need to update the User Interface depending on the user's location. I started using `dispatch_get_global_queue` because the user interface was unresponsive while the web call was performed.

Now, my problem is that the buttons do not appear correctly when buttonUpdate is called. One button is supposed to be black, and the other is green. However, now they both appear the default blue. Also, the words/title of the buttons do not appear until I click on one of them. Anyone know why? Thank you!

**I have this method called `preButtonUpdate` that calls the buttonUpdate method asynchronously:**

```
-(void)preButtonUpdate { 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
            [self buttonUpdate];
        });   
    }
```

**The preButtonUpdate method is called in viewDidAppear and appReturnsActive:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self preButtonUpdate];
    //other code
}

- (void)appReturnsActive {

    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;

    //ONLY WANT TO PERFORM THE UPDATE IF VIEWING THE PROFILE VIEW CONTROLLER
    UIViewController *currentVC = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
    NSString * name = NSStringFromClass([currentVC class]);
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"ProfileViewController"]) { 

        [self preButtonUpdate];    
    }
}
```

**Then, the preButtonUpdate calls the buttonUpdate method, which performs the web query and updates the user interface:**

```
-(void) buttonUpdate {
    [locationManagerProfile stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSString *userLatitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
    getUserLatitude];
    NSString *userLongitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
    getUserLongitude];

    NSString *placeLatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"savedLatitude"];

    NSString *placeLongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"savedLongitude"];

    NSString *distanceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?
    lat1=%@&lon1=%@&lat2=%@&lon2=%@",userLatitude, userLongitude, placeLatitude, 
    placeLongitude];

    NSData *distanceURLResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
    URLWithString:distanceURL]];

    NSString *distanceInFeet = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:distanceURLResult 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([distanceInFeet isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button A" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionA)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor 
        colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];  
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGoTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button B" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionB)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGoTwo; 
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnGo, 
        btnGoTwo, nil];
    }
    if ([distanceInFeet isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button C" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionC)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor 
        colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];        
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGoTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button B" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionB)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGoTwo;   
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnGo, 
        btnGoTwo, nil];
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UI Update` is always done on the main thread. So keep your UI update code out of the `despatch queue`

Keep `[self buttonUpdate];` out of the `dispatch_async` block

```
-(void)preButtonUpdate { 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
            [self buttonUpdate];
        });   
    }
```

[Unblocking Your User Interface - Apple Developer](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/UnblockUI.html&ei=CwDIUeC1AsHUygHn74GgCQ&usg=AFQjCNGP0KtL8UE7BUr8T_xLg0s0ILWjZQ&sig2=WRT3QRdmnzhNGY94YWcgSA&bvm=bv.48293060,d.aWc)

**EDIT**:

**Put the if condtion code just outside the `dispatch_async` block**

Comment: thanks! I put it in there because I have a `dataWithContentsOfURL` call that is causing the app to lag while the call is performed. I need to wait for the result of this web call so that I know how to update the UI. How would I do this if I remove buttonUpdate from the dispatch_async?

Comment: try removeing buttonUpdate from the dispatch_async block. I think it should work as u like it to but with a lag. To remove the lag you can use http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions